# What is the correct way to handle prompt method when testing javascript (using karma, jasmine, webstorm)

Tags: javascript, tdd, bdd, karma-jasmine

I have this line in my code:

```
var textThatWillBeChanged = prompt("Paste the text you would like to change!");
```

In the browser it asks the user to enter a text.

Questions:

1. How can I write tests that feed the desired input values using karma and jasmine?
2. What is the correct methodology to handle situations like these in Javascript?

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one.

Comment: You want to separate the logic to get the user input from the logic that handles the user input so you can test the handler separate from the user input. When you run your test you will only test the handler portion of your code. In order to be more specific than that, you would need to supply additional code.

Comment: Thanks, more modularity is good suggestion. I believe there is a way to forse-set in javascript, but do not remeber it - can you remind me? Is there any way of mocking the prompt function before the execution of a test?